# How to test for many conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I force `section` to be either `asd` or `alg` or `sys` or `data` or `sim` or `se` ?

If I use regex like below, then `datadfghdg` would be allowed.

```
if (section == '') {
    alert('Section is required');
} else if (!(/asd|alg|sys|data|img|se/.test(section))) {
    alert('Section must be one of: asd alg sys data img se');
} else {
    is_okay = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the strings to be at the beginning and and of the regex by using `^` and ^$` respectively:

```
if( !(/^(asd|alg|sys|data|img|se)$/.test(section)) )
    ...
```

Alternatively you can use `in` to achieve this as well:

```
if( section in { 'asd':'','alg':'', ... } )
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add ^ to the beginning and $ to the end of the regex.

/^(asd|alg|sys|data|img|se)$/

Comment: That won't work; the ^ will only apply to the `asd` option, and the $ only applies to `se`. Brackets are required.

Comment: Yeah I forgot the parens. It's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Try with /^(asd|alg|sys|data|img|se)$/.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex `/^(asd|alg|sys|data|img|se)$/`.